# Can't import Ink interpreter with Javascript interpreter with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I need to make a Vue.js site with a JavaScript Ink interpreter. The only one that seems to be production-ready is [Ink.js](https://github.com/y-lohse/inkjs). There are two ways to import it. One is in its TypeScript format, but my Vue setup does not use TypeScript. I could add it, maybe, although I'm not sure I want to. If I import the TypeScript libraries from Yarn, no matter which object I import, it shows up with a value of `undefined` in my code.

Then [there is a pure es5 script available](https://github.com/y-lohse/inkjs/releases/tag/v1.11.0), that seems to be a transpiled version of the first one, but when I try to import that one, I get this error, I think from Babel:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!'
    cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Ink.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:39 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!'
at Object../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Ink.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:962)
```

My guess is that Babel is set up for es6 or es7 and the pure is5 file brings up some unexpected syntax. I tried to change `babel.config.js`, but I've found no option that's kept Vue.js from complaining. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After many failed attempts, I went around the problem in the following way: I imported the `Story` object directly from the library:

```
import { Story } from '../../node_modules/inkjs/engine/Story';
// ...
let story = new Story(storyText);
```

I know it's not what the documentation recommends, but it works. And it seems everything else that needs to be imported is, because when I try to read `story.currentChoices` I get an array of `Choice` objects that are in turn perfectly readable.

So this works for me. If anyone else runs into this problem, I'm not saying it's the *right* solution, I'm just saying that's what I finally ended up doing.